# Which is equivalent for PHP Include at CodeIgniter3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Please explain to me how to do it:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['s'])) {
    $_GET['s'] = ""; }
    if ($_GET['s'] == "") { include("Templates/Tutorial/1.tpl"); }
    if ($_GET['s'] == "1") { include("Templates/Tutorial/1.tpl"); }
    if ($_GET['s'] == "2") { include("Templates/Tutorial/2.tpl"); }
    if ($_GET['s'] == "3") { include("Templates/Tutorial/3.tpl"); }
    if ($_GET['s'] == "4") { include("Templates/Tutorial/4.tpl"); }
    if ($_GET['s'] == "5") { include("Templates/Tutorial/5.tpl"); }
?>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: $this->load->view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will also work

```
<?php
    $inc = 1;
    if(isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s'] != ""):
        $inc = (int)$_GET['s'];
    endif;

    include("Templates/Tutorial/$inc.tpl");
?>
```

Comment: Glad i could help you, Are you trying to call smarty templates into Codeigniter ?

Comment: I try to learn working with MVC from CodeIgniter and use as study material one project found on github.

Comment: Note this answer is pure PHP, with nothing specific to CodeIgniter.